Import of aggregated LCIA results (e.g. cradle-to-gate) in brightway2
In a Brightway2 project, I would like to import several activities (e.g. production of a gas), for which I only have aggregated LCIA results according to the LCIA method CML. I therefore have data on their environmental impacts in the CML categories, but do not know the LCI data. The mentioned activities are again inputs of other activities in the project (e.g. the gas is used in another process). In the end I would like to analyse the LCIA results of different activities using the CML method. Does anyone know how I can best import the activities for which I only know the cumulative LCIA results (and not the LCI data) so that I can use them in the further calculations?
I have read about the Brightway2-aggregated package (How to import aggregated (i.e. cradle-to-gate) at the LCIA score level?) but I am not sure if it is the right tool for my application or if I need the LCI data for the activities to use it.
